# 502 gateway on successful deployment from docker container throws 502 gateways error

Tags: deployment

He Heroku community,

I'm facing 502 gateway error on my domain https://secure-dawn-68418.herokuapp.com/ after successful deployment.

Need your help on this

Want app successfully run with 200 status code

Comment: Please share more details of the error that you're seeing, and provide logs if possible

Comment: ---> a500be7ccb8a
Successfully built a500be7ccb8a
Successfully tagged 2890dca029635a28e22bc14c818e444e285dbe7d:latest
=== Pushing release (Dockerfile)
Tagged image "2890dca029635a28e22bc14c818e444e285dbe7d" as "registry.heroku.com/secure-dawn-68418/release"
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/secure-dawn-68418/release]
4efcd4003c84: Mounted from secure-dawn-68418/release
latest: digest: sha256:da5503a36bbcbeb1dacde18b443ab0bab288735e7a8185a2a57238f806e495a7 size: 3056

Comment: Is that all there is in the logs?

Comment: yes. these all are the logs after deployment